# Drawing everything in drawRect: rather than using subviews

Tags: ios, animation

I read this article about ["Simple Strategies for Smooth Animation on the iPhone"](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/simple-strategies-smooth-animation-iphone). It's about how to do optimization when you create a custom table view cell.

It said :

> "A naive implementation of a Tweet cell might include a UILabel for
>   the username, a UILabel for the tweet text, a UIImageView for the
>   avatar, and so on"

Then it said :

> "Instead, our Tweet cells contain a single view with no subviews; a
>   single drawRect: draws everything.
>
> We institutionalized direct drawing by creating a generic table view
>   cell class that accepts a block for its drawRect: method. This is, by
>   far, the most commonly used cell in the app."

What does this mean?
You cannot create `UILabel` only from drawing it right?